# How to create variable using a code in python

Tags: python, variables

Is there a way to create new variables with a piece of code in python?
For example if I needed to use `input("what's your name?")`
and create a variable for each answer such as `name1` for the first answer, `name2`, `name3` etc...`
How would you do this?

Comment: Use a list and do `names.append(input)`.

Answer (score 2):

Fairly simple:

```
name1 = input("What is your name? ")
```

should work.

To get a variable amount of names you could put them into a list:

```
number_names = int(input("How many names do you want? "))

names = []

for i in range(number_names):
    names.append(input("What is your name? "))

for name in names:
    print(name)
```

And as an afterthought, if you insist on using `name1, name2` etc. instead of `name[1], name[2]`... You can use a dictionary:

```
number_names = int(input("How many names do you want? "))

names = {}

for i in range(number_names):
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    names['name'+str(i)] = name

print(names['name1']) # Assumming there are at least 2 names in the dict
```

Worth noting that I've assumed you are using python 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for creating variables

```
n=3
for i in range(n):
    var = input("what's your name?")
    globals()['name'+str(i)] = var #or locals()['name'+str(i)] if you want variables in a local scope, (inside a function)

print(name0,name1,name2) # upto n-1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could uses `exec` but that doesn't mean that you should use `exec`.

```
for i in range(5):
    exec("name%d=raw_input('enter something ')" % (i + 1))

print name1
print name2
print name3
print name4
print name5
```